# Prolog: Generating Every Possibility of a List Given a Pattern

Tags: list, prolog

Let's say you have a list in Prolog such as: [3,4,2,2,1,4]. How would one go about generating a list of lists of all possible patterns that start at the first element of the list, then either go to the i + 2th element, or the i + 3rd element, and so on from there.

Example:
Say I have [3,4,2,2,1,4,8].
I want to be able to generate a list of lists such as:
[[3,2,1,8], [3,2,4], [3,2,8]]

I.e. all possibilities of either every other element or every i+3 element, or any other combination, such as i+2,i+3,i+2,i+2, etc.

I've implemented my own version of a powerset, but I can't seem to figure out where to start.

Comment: If you are trying to capture, say, ever 3rd element, you could use something like, `foo([H1,H2,H3|T], [H1|R]) :- foo(T,R).` If you want to parameterize how many you're skipping, use could a counter.

Comment: If there is a list, I'm looking for a way to generate all possibilities of the following: start at the first element of the list, then either go to the third element or the fourth element. From there either go to the current + 2th element or the current + 3rd element, and so on. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: My comment wasn't intended as a complete answer, but just to give a couple of nudges that will help. Although looking at your example, it seems your results have varying intervals between elements. `[3,2,4]` selects 1st, 3rd, and 6th (intervals of 2 and then 3) or 1st, 4th, and 6th (intervals of 3 and 2). So I wasn't exactly sure what you were getting at.

Comment: Why do you want this? It is much more common to **not** generate such a set explicitly but only to generate corresponding solutions that are then filtered or whatever. This saves a lot of space.

Answer (score 1):

```
gen([], []).
gen([A], [A]).
gen([A, _ | T], [A | Xs]) :- gen(T, Xs).
gen([A, _, _ | T], [A | Xs]) :- gen(T, Xs).
```

results in

```
?- gen([3,4,2,2,1,4,8], X).
X = [3, 2, 1, 8] ;
X = [3, 2, 1] ;
X = [3, 2, 4] ;
X = [3, 2, 4] ;
X = [3, 2, 8] ;
false.
```

You can use `findall/3` to get all results

```
?- findall(X, gen([3,4,2,2,1,4,8], X), Z).
Z = [[3, 2, 1, 8], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 4], [3, 2, 4], [3, 2, 8]].
```