# Possible list permutation using a given formula

Tags: list, prolog, permutation

I am trying to get my head wrap around lists in Prolog. To do this I am trying to create a sort of game. You pass in a list of numbers 1-9 that can be repeated, the list can be any length. The rules are that starting from the first element(e) you can only move to e+2 or e+3 until you get to the end. The goal is to "land" on the highest numbers. In essence it is kind of like hopscotch. The problem I am running into is determining all the possible permutation for paths. So far I have the following.

```
paths([], []). %empty list returns empty list
paths([X], [X]). %list with one element returns that one element
paths([X1, X2], [X1]). %list with 2 elements returns the first element
paths([X1, X2, X3], [X1,X3]). %list with three elements returns the first and third element
paths() :- % the recursive case for a list with 4+ elements
```

An list to use would be: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,7,9,3,6,5,7,8,9]`
I need to determine all possible paths using the rule mentioned about. I wish lists could be indexed in Prolog :(

Any logic guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36579234/prolog-generating-every-possibility-of-a-list-given-a-pattern) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The requirements aren't completely clear, but it seems that:

- The second argument is required to have the same first element as the
  first argument (you "hop" on the first "square" first always, using
  your hopscotch metaphore)
- You aren't requiring that the last element of the first list be the
  last element of the second list (you aren't requiring that you "land
  on" the last "square").
- An empty list succeeds with an empty list result (rather than just failing on an empty list - which is another valid approach).

Then this could be implemented as follows. You do not need many explicit 2- and 3-element list cases since they are handled by the recursive clause and simpler base cases.

```
path([], []).
path([X], [X]).
path([X,_|T], [X|R]) :-   % hop over 1 element
    path(T, R).
path([X,_,_|T], [X|R]) :- % hop over 2 elements
    path(T, R).
```

For a simple example:

```
| ?- path([1,2,3,4,5,6], R).

R = [1,3,5] ? ;

R = [1,3,6] ? ;

R = [1,4,6] ? ;

R = [1,4]

yes
```

If I don't have your requirements exactly right, you should be able to adjust this to suit your needs as it shows how to handle a recursive case. It also sounds like you are headed in the direction of trying to optimize the values in your hops, which I shall also leave as an exercise.

This can also be done with a DCG (definite clause grammar)

```
path([]) --> [].
path([X]) --> [X].
path([X|T]) --> ([X,_] | [X,_,_]), path(T).
```

Which would be exercised:

```
| ?- phrase(path(R), [1,2,3,4,5,6]).

R = [1,3,5] ? ;

R = [1,3,6] ? ;

R = [1,4,6] ? ;

R = [1,4] ? ;

(1 ms) no
| ?-
```

---

In light of the extra requirement that the last step taken must be one that falls within the list, here is an updated version of the `path/2` predicate:

```
path([], []).
path([X], [X]).
path([X,_], [X]).
path([X,_,Y|T], [X|R]) :-   % hop over 1 element
    path([Y|T], R).
path([X,_,_,Y|T], [X|R]) :- % hop over 2 elements
    path([Y|T], R).
```

Comment: This is close, but I think I came up with the solution. Will post below

Comment: @ZackHerbert if you found my answer useful, perhaps you could upvote it. Your requirements weren't totally clear, so I did not expect to hit your exact needs. However, this answer should be plenty of help in understanding how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is a reason to avoid [indexing](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=nth1/3): simplicity. If you decompose your problem, maybe you could start writing a step/3 predicate like

```
step([_,X|T],X,T).
step([_,_,X|T],X,T).
```

and then

```
paths([],[]).
paths(L,[X|Xs]) :- step(L,X,T), paths(T,Xs).
```

note: I don't understand very well your game, some example of playground and solution would be welcome.

Comment: Indexing is very unusual to use in this sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
%passing in a list and return all possible paths using K+2 or K+3 with K being the first element of the list.
%empty list returns empty list
%list with one element returns that one element
%list with 2 elements returns the first element
%list with three elements returns the first and third element
%list with four/four+ elements needs to be called recursively, prefix them with the first element and append them together
%RL means ReturnList
%FL means FinalList
%List is the appended list containing all the paths
paths([], []). 
paths([X], [[X]]). 
paths([X1, X2], [[X1]]). 
paths([X1, X2, X3], [[X1,X3]]). 
paths([X1, X2, X3, X4 | T], List) :-
   paths([X3,X4|T], RL), paths([X4|T], RL2), 
   prefix_all(X1, RL, FL1), prefix_all(X1, RL2, FL2), 
   append(FL1, FL2, List).
```

So if run with the list `[1,2,3,4,5]` is would produce the following:

```
| ?- paths([1,2,3,4,5],X). 

X = [[1,3,5],[1,4]] ? ;
no
```

Comment: Why is `[1,3]` not a valid path which skips the 2 elements 4 and 5 at the end? Also, you can get the full list result with my answer using `findall/3`: `findall(P, path([1,2,3,4,5], P), Paths).` which is a good use of `findall/3`, separating the logic of the relation to define a path from the logic to collect all the solutions.

Comment: @lurker Because you have to go to the end of the list. So you must move e+2 or e+3 every time if you can. Sorry if the rules were unclear in the beginning.

Comment: `[1,3]` does just move e+2 or e+3 every time. For the list `[1,2,3,4,5]`, start at 1. Go e+2, to get to 3. So the path is `[1,3]`. Then go e+3 to go just past 5. Why would it be different than your `[1,4]` solution, which starts at 1, goes e+3 to get to 4, then goes e+2 to go just past 5?

Comment: @lerkerbecause at the point that you have [1,3] 3 is now e, e+2 does not extend past the end of the list so you have to go there. If you are at e and e+2 or e+3 extends past the list you can't move again.

Comment: I updated my answer with a new version of `path/2` which I think meets your requirement.